# Equivalence classes modulo 7 are pairwise disjoint

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Where do I got from here? I really really have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

If $y \in A_n$, then $y \equiv n \pmod{7}$, so there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $y - n = 7k$.  If $y \in A_m$, then $y \equiv m \pmod{7}$, so there exists $l \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $y - m = 7l$.  Hence,

\begin{align*}
(y - n) - (y - m) & = 7k - 7l\\
m - n  & = 7(k - l)\\
\end{align*}

Since the integers are closed under subtraction $k - l \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Therefore, $m \equiv n \pmod{7} \Rightarrow A_n = A_m$.

Comment: is that all I have to do?

Comment: You have to show that if $A_m \cap A_n \neq \emptyset$, then $A_m = A_n$.  What I did was to show that if $y \in A_m \cap A_n$, then $m \equiv n \pmod{7}$, which means $m$ and $n$ are in the same equivalence class modulo $7$.  Therefore, $A_m = A_n$.

Comment: how do I show that?

Comment: You show that by giving the argument I provided in my answer.  I apologize for not making that clear.

Comment: so I put the Am intersect An does not equal the empty set after your last line in our first answer?

Comment: What I did is continue the proof of the second case.  You assumed that $A_m \cap A_n \neq \emptyset$, which allowed you to conclude that there exists $y \in A_m \cap A_n$.  I then showed that this assumption implied $A_m = A_n$ since you wanted to show that either $A_m \cap A_n = \emptyset$ or $A_m = A_n$.